# Pass a null value to an objectdatasource from dropdownlist default

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I would like to pass a parameter to an objectdatasource from a dropdownlist.  The first Item of the dropdownlist reads "AllProducts" but when I pass it to the stored proc in the datasource i would actually like it to read null as the default.  How can I do this?

```
ddlProdSuite.DataSource = pscmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlProdSuite.DataTextField = "PRODUCT";
ddlProdSuite.DataValueField = "PRODUCT";
ddlProdSuite.DataBind();
psConn.Close();
ddlProdSuite.Items.Insert(0, "AllProducts");
```

Comment: You should generally tag what language you are working in.

Comment: I've added the tags @crashmstr

Comment: Can you please put code which you are using for passing data to stored procedure?